# Inclusion vs Embedding

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, model-theory

I'm currently studying splitting field extensions in Galois theory, and [the book](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) I'm using for a reference keeps saying that there are always field extensions $\mathbb{F}'$ of a non-algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$ which 'contain' $\mathbb{F}$.

Is this a sloppy use of language where the author is actually talking about a canonical field homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{F}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}'$ with $\ker{\phi^{-1}}=\mathbb{F}'\setminus\phi(\mathbb{F})$ which serves as an embedding, where $\ker{\phi^{-1}}=\{y\in\mathbb{F}':\nexists x\in\mathbb{F}\big[\phi(x)=y\big]\}$, or is $\mathbb{F}$ legitimately included in $\mathbb{F}'$?

This is confusing to me primarily because the machinery through which the author constructs $\mathbb{F}'$ over $\mathbb{F}$ is as a quotient ring by a maximal ideal $\mathcal{I}$ in $\mathbb{F}[X]$, so $\mathbb{F}'=\mathbb{F}[X]\setminus\mathcal{I}.$ In this case $\mathbb{F}'$ definitely does not "include" $\mathbb{F}$ in any non-lazy sense, since the objects in $\mathbb{F}'$ are second order objects over $\mathbb{F}[X]$.

Despite this, there is some later discussion about the (non)uniqueness of algebraic closures in the sense that there are many isomorphic but non-equivalent sets that form the algebraic closure of a given field, primarily as a result of the non-constructive process of algebriac closure. This makes me wonder -- is the author implicitly assuming that $\mathbb{F}'$ is *actually* an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{F}[X]\setminus\mathcal{I}$ which has the elements of $\mathbb{F}$ as first order objects contained in it?

I believe that this is a concern somewhat outside the usual domain of things field theorists care about, so I have added the model theory tag as it seems more appropriate to the question at hand.

Comment: Any homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb F \longrightarrow \mathbb F'$ is injective. So we can identify $\mathbb F$ with it's image and consider $\mathbb F$ as a subfield of $\mathbb F'$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $\ker{\phi^{-1}}=\mathbb{F}'\setminus\phi(\mathbb{F})$.  What is "$\phi^{-1}$", and in what sense does it have a "kernel"?

Comment: @EricWofsey Every function $f:\mathbb{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{Y}$ canonically induces functions on powersets $f_n:\mathcal{P}^n\mathbb{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}^n\mathbb{Y}$ which we usually abuse the notation of and still write as $f$; for example, the standard open-set definition of continuity in topology abuses this notion when it writes $f^{-1}(U)$ for the inverse image of an open set under the induced powerfunction.  In my case I am simply writing that the induced inverse powerfunction maps the complement of the image of $\phi$ onto the empty set. This is common in general topology, no?

Comment: Ah, OK.  You should know that no one else will know what you're talking about if you refer to $\ker\phi^{-1}$ like this.  If you want to say such a thing, you should mention in words that by $\phi^{-1}$ you are referring to the induced map on power sets.  (It is standard to use $\phi^{-1}$ for the induced map on power sets, but not to refer to its kernel like this in a context where you have not mentioned the power sets explicitly.)

Comment: @EricWofsey The irony of my omission is not lost on me in a post where I complain about sloppy language! Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is hardly restricted to the context of field theory: it is found throughout all of mathematics.  Basically, whenever you have a chosen embedding of one set into another, it is extremely common to pretend it is actually a subset.  For instance, using any of the standard constructions of the real numbers from the rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$; instead there is just a canonical embedding $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Yet in almost all contexts, we say $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$, identifying it with its image under the embedding.  You can think of this as a sloppy use of language, as you say, but it is a sloppy use that is completely standard and used *constantly* in math.

In the particular case of your author, I don't know whether they intend to be talking about embeddings, or intend to be modifying the sets so they are actually subsets.  For most purposes, if you want to be strictly rigorous, it is more convenient to define everything in terms of embeddings, so when you say something "contains $\mathbb{F}$" you really mean there is a chosen embedding of $\mathbb{F}$ into it.  But I have no doubt that for everything they do, it doesn't actually matter.

As for the point about algebraic closures, I don't know what discussion you're talking about or what you mean by "isomorphic but non-equivalent".  I'm guessing that the point of that discussion is that a field can have algebraic closures which are isomorphic as field extensions, but there is no canonical *choice* of isomorphism between them.  Moreover, two different algebraic closures may have additional natural structures (besides just being field extensions of your base field) which are not isomorphic to each other.  None of this has anything to do with the technicalities of underlying sets you are worrying about.

Comment: I tend to think of everything as classes, so these things bog me down when I'm reading through a new subject; I greatly appreciate the clarification!